# How to check if image has an alpha channel

Tags: windows, winapi, wic

I'm loading an image using the Windows Imaging Component. I can easily find out the pixel format of the image by calling `IWICBitmapSource::GetPixelFormat()`. I can also easily find out the number of bits per pixel and the number of channels by using the `IWICPixelFormatInfo` interface.

But how can I find out if one of the channels is an alpha channel? Of course, I could go ahead and manually compare the `WICPixelFormatGUID` obtained from `IWICBitmapSource::GetPixelFormat()` against [MSDN's list of WIC image formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-codec-native-pixel-formats) but this is a very inconvenient way because there are dozens of different formats I'd have to compare it against and it's also not very future-proof in case more formats are added in the future.

So is there a better way to tell if one of the image's channels is an alpha channel?

Comment: IWICPixelFormatInfo2::SupportsTransparency? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicpixelformatinfo2-supportstransparency

Comment: @SimonMourier: Yes, that does the job. Thanks a lot! If you want to post this as an official answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [IWICPixelFormatInfo2::SupportsTransparency method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicpixelformatinfo2-supportstransparency). Note this interface may not be always supported though.